# Выборка товаров за неделю

Tags: sql-server, выборка

Подскажите, как сделать выборку товаров за неделю. Тип данных Date.

Данный способ не работает:

```
SELECT Sum(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count) as Summa
FROM Sales, Goods
WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(D, 7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEADD(D, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()

Comment: Спасибо. :) А можно ещё уточнить код для данных за месяц?

Comment: Вообще, вместо "D, -7" лучше написать "wk, -1" (или ww, не помню точно). Аналогично с месяцем - "mm, -1" (или как-то так).